# Read a list of files one by one from different folder in python

Tags: python, image, file, python-imaging-library, file-handling

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for dirct in dirs:
    lis_sal_map =[]
    gt = ''
    for name in files:
    
       (base, ext) = os.path.splitext(name) # split base and extension
        if ext in ('.jpg'):          # check the extension
            gt = name
            print("gt old is", gt)
        if ext in ('.png'):
        #full_name = os.path.join(root, name)
            lis_sal_map.append(name)
    print("list sal map", lis_sal_map) 
        
    
print("gt before file", gt)
img_gt = Image.open(gt)
numpydata_in = np.array(img_gt).astype('uint8')
numpydata_out = list_sal_map[0]
nss = nss(numpydata_in, numpydata_out)
print("nss is", nss)
```

I have 18 folders each containing 10 images, with one as ground truth and others as predicted images. I am trying to write a program that will access these 18 folders one by one and compare the images within each folder. Can you help me with where it is going wrong? The current output that I am getting is like below:

```
list sal map []
list sal map []
gt befoe file 
Traceback (most recent call last):

fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Trace back (most recent call last):
File "result_auto.py", line 61, in <module>
img_gt = Image.open(gt)
File "anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2897, in open
fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: what's the value of `gt`? please present a [mre].

Comment: I think you check extension in wrong way - so finally you get empty string in `gt`. You could use `print()` to see which part of your code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing. OR at least you should check what you have in `gt` before `open()` because it can't open empty string. `if gt != "": ...open.image...` or shorter `if gt: ...open.image...`

Comment: if you want to do something with many files then you should do it directly inside `for`-loop - in place of `gt = name`

Comment: to check extension you can do `if name.lower().endswith('.jpg'):` or for many extensions you can use tuple `if name.lower().endswith( ('.jpg', '.png') ):`